# a+ command in python reads but does not append

Tags: python, file, permissions

For example, I have a text file that contains 4 lines of this statement "this is shirin" when I run the following code nothing happens on my file:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'a+')
for i in file:
    if len(i) == 0 or 'this' in i:
        file.write('test')
file.close()
```

Comment: You used `w+` instead of `a`

Comment: The code you showed has `w+`; maybe show a [mre]?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `+` unless you're also reading the file.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I made a mistake on my question, please review it again :) also if I remove + it returns this error: not readable.

Comment: @RandomDavis sorry I edited my question please review it again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the file in append mode, the initial position is at the end, so there's nothing to read and the loop ends immediately. You need to rewind to the beginning of the file to read. And if you want to keep reading, you need to seek again after writing at the end.

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    while True:
        i = file.readline()
        if not i:
            break
        oldpos = file.tell()
        if 'this' in i:
            file.write('test')
            file.seek(oldpos)
```

Comment: I got it but it returns this error **OSError: telling position disabled by next() call**

Comment: Need to use explicit `readline()` calls.

Comment: it worked, thanks a bunch.